# Finding (and counting) duplicate JS/Java files

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

I have the following script which takes minutes to give output.

```
printf "\nDuplicate JS Filenames...\n"
(
  find . -name '*.js' -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 ";
  echo "$(find . -type f -name '*.js' | wc -l) JS files in search directory";
  echo "$(find . -name '*.js' -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 " | wc -l) duplicates found";
)

printf "\nDuplicate Java Filenames...\n"
(
  find . -name '*.java' -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 ";
  echo "$(find . -type f -name '*.java' | wc -l) Java files in search directory";
  echo "$(find . -name '*.java' -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 " | wc -l) duplicates found";
)
```

I know that I make the same request, or similar ones, a couple of times.

How could I optimize this, and maybe already the base command - I'm surprised that find takes so long, or is it due to sort, uniq, and grep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from running essentially the same `find` command three times, the main issue is that you run a separate `basename` instance for every single found file.

If you are using GNU `find` (verify with `find --version`), you can get find to print the basenames directly:

```
find . -name '*.js' -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

On my system this is about 900  times faster than calling `basename` when run on a directory with about 200,000 files in it.

If your system does not come with GNU `find` (e.g. MacOS, OpenBSD, FreeBSD) and you do not want to install it (the package is usually called `findutils`), you can use `sed` to do the same as `basename` but for all found files at once:

```
find . -name '*.js' -type f | sed 's@.*/@@'
```

On my system this is only slightly slower than using `-printf`.

---

If you want to reduce the amount of times you run `find`, you can just save the output in a variable:

```
filelist="$(find . -name '*.js' -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort)"
echo "$filelist" | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 ";
echo "$(echo "$filelist" | wc -l) JS files in search directory";
echo "$(echo "$filelist" | uniq -c | grep -v "^[ \t]*1 " | wc -l) duplicates found"
```

Note that on `bash` you need to put double-quotes around `$filelist` so that the newlines are not squashed.

Comment: Alternatively, check whether your basename accepts `--multiple` arguments.

Comment: On my system, the answer is given now in 1.2 sec instead of 134.9 sec. Thanks a lot!  And thanks for given explanations which allow me to learn at the same time...

Comment: A question: let's say I'm never interested in seeing some duplicate files (whose name would be hard-coded, such as `package-info.java`, `AllTests.java` and `Constants.java`), how could I remove those lines from the output?  I guess chaining `grep -v` commands one after the other is not the right solution...

Comment: Question posted as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190215/how-to-remove-some-lines-from-the-shell-output-not-chaining-grep-commands